# ReactiveUI-5.99.6: ReactiveCommand CanExecute always returns False

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI-5.99.6 but i'm having trouble making this simple test pass

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<int> List { get; private set; }
    public IReactiveCommand Command { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        List = new ReactiveList<int>();
        Command = ReactiveCommand.Create(List.Changed.Select(_ => List.Any()));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();

        vm.List.Add(2);
        Assert.IsTrue(vm.Command.CanExecute(null));
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: There has never been a release 5.99.6, we had a 5.5.1 then we jumped to 6.0.0. We are currently at 8.7.2. Have you got version numbers confused?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade from 4.6.5. I downloaded this version https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/5.99.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about version 5.99.6 (!?) but the following implementation should make your unit test pass in version 8.7.2:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<int> List { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        List = new ReactiveList<int>();
        Command = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { /* do something */ }, List.Changed.Select(_ => List.Any()));
    }
}
```

If you change the type of the `Command` property to anything else than `ICommand` (for example `ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit>`), your unit test would look something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.List.Add(2);
    Assert.IsTrue(await vm.Command.CanExecute.FirstAsync());
}
```

> What version should i get if my project is .Net 4.5?

ReactiveUI [7.4.0](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/download/7.4.0/ReactiveUI.7.4.0.nupkg) supports .NET Framework 4.5. The solution above should work for this version as well.

Comment: What versione should i get if my project is .Net 4.5? Version 8 is .Net 4.6 only right?

Comment: @Dtex: [7.4.0](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/download/7.4.0/ReactiveUI.7.4.0.nupkg) supports .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: No, the project is quite big and upgrading to 7.4.0 broke pretty much every single class. I'm starting to wonder if upgrading is really doable for us.

Comment: The project was built with version 4.6.5 since it started as .Net 4.0. Now we switched to .Net 4.5 and i was trying to see if we could update ReactiveUI, but with all the breaking changes I don't know if it's actually worth the effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179641/discussion-between-dtex-and-mm8).